# SetAdapter is crashing Android studio in Fragment for spinner

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, spinner

When I comment out `setAdapter` line, the program does not crash.

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

final Spinner mySpinner = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);

ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity(), R.array.spinnerArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_personal_data_fragment, container, false);

    return view;
}
```

I've tried using `new` `ArrayAdapter` instead `createFromResource` but that didn't work either.  And I've put everything in `OnCreateView` method so that doesn't help. I know I'm missing something, I tried this in `MainActivity` and it works fine.

Comment: Can you post your complete code of fragment. You are missing `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, parentViewGroup, false);`
       `return rootView;` and you put your code between view.

Comment: I've added it, and put it there, and it still crashes with the setAdapter

Comment: can you share error logcat

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at aninterface.bondsj.com.srbuilder.InputPersonalDataFragment.onCreateView(InputPersonalDataFragment.java:43)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
        
**All I could fit**

Comment: Can you post your complete code of fragment with xml

Comment: <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/metatypeSpinner"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:entries="@array/MetatypeSpinnerArray"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/feetText" />    **This is the actual code for xml**

Comment: Ok so found a workaround for the crash, but definitely not a desired outcome.  I included <include layout="@layout/input_personal_data_fragment" /> in my activity_main.xml below my AppBarLayout, and it fixed the crash(didn't change anything else).  However, it displayed the fragment INSIDE the toolbar.......weird.

Comment: WOOHOO!!!!  I figured it out.  Just changed getActivity() to view on the findViewbyID line.  That's it

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to inflate your layout in `onCreateView` while using `fragment` and then do `findViewById` on that view reference that you are returning from `onCreateView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

**Problem was you are not inflate a view**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manual, container, false);

String [] values = 
    {"demo1","demo2","demo3","demo4","demo5"};
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

return v;

}
```

it helps you.

Comment: I tried that and it still crashes.  Any other ideas?